# Know if a basis is orthonormal just with a few dot products

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following dot products results

> $\langle(1,0),(1,0)\rangle =4$
> $\langle(1,1),(1,1)\rangle = 1$
> $\langle(1,0),(3,3)\rangle =0$

I can't find a way to know if the following bases are orthonormal

> i) $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ 
> ii) $\{(1/2 ,0),(0,1)\}$
> iii) $\{(1/\sqrt{5}\cdot(0,1) ,(-1,1)\}$
> iv)
> $\{1/\sqrt{5}\cdot(0,1), 1/\sqrt{20}\cdot(5,4)\}$

I just know that i) it's not, because $\langle(1,0),(1,0)\rangle=4$
How can I approach the other parts?

Comment: So these vectors are expressed in some other basis, or else the inner product is not the standard one.  I expect you need to make plentiful use of linearity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(1,0)$ is orthogonal to $(3,3)$, then it is orthogonal to $(1,1)$ as well.  That's the only orthogonality you have, so you have to use it.

Now since $(1,1) - (1,0) = (0,1)$, you can find out whether $(0,1)$ is normalized or not, which will give you a partial answer to ii).

I expect they will all be solved with similar linear combinations.